# how to store updated stock data in dynamic array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, trading

I am fetching live value i.e. ftse from yahoo finance, using ajax and php.
I want to store all value in an array format and want to compare last 2 recently updated values.

following is my **javascript**:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ftse.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
setInterval(loadXMLDoc,1000);
</script>
```

following is my **php code**.

```
<div id="myDiv">


<?php
// Setup Variables
$stockList = "^ftse";
$f = "l1";
$host = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv";
$requestUrl = $host."?s=".$stockList."&f=".$f."&e=.csv";

// Pull data (download CSV as file)
$filesize=2000;
$handle = fopen($requestUrl, "r");
$raw = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);

// Split results, trim way the extra line break at the end
$quotes = explode("\n\n",trim($raw));

foreach($quotes as $quoteraw) {
$quoteraw = str_replace(", I", " I", $quoteraw);
$quote = explode(",", $quoteraw);

// output the first element of the array, the Company Name
}


echo "<br><center><font size='30' color='green'>".$raw."<br>";


?>

</div>
```

following is my **ftse.php** code.

```
<?php
// Setup Variables
$stockList = "^ftse";
$f = "l1";
$host = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv";
$requestUrl = $host."?s=".$stockList."&f=".$f."&e=.csv";

// Pull data (download CSV as file)
$filesize=2000;
$handle = fopen($requestUrl, "r");
$raw = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);

// Split results, trim way the extra line break at the end
$quotes = explode("\n\n",trim($raw));

foreach($quotes as $quoteraw) {
$quoteraw = str_replace(", I", " I", $quoteraw);
$quote = explode(",", $quoteraw);

// output the first element of the array, the Company Name
}

echo "<br><center><font size='30' color='green'>".$raw."<br>";
```

?>

Problem is if the value is smaller then should be printed in red and if greater then in green color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no property `color` on the element. You want to set a style to set the color to green, so you would write:

```
echo "<br><center><font size='30' style='color=green'>".$raw."<br>";
```

Ideally you wouldn't do this because it just pollutes the DOM. Annotate with a class:

```
echo "<br><center><font size='30' class='up'>".$raw."<br>";
echo "<br><center><font size='30' class='down'>".$raw."<br>";
```

Then in your CSS file you just have:

```
.up {
  color: green
}

.down {
  color: red
}
```

While you are at it, also move the font size and other style decorations to the CSS.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What u have suggest was correct but we don't need to print both green and red color result. we have to print one from this according to the precedence value i.e. if value is low then red otherwise green and we have to compare this value from previous value. Can u please guide me how to compare those value. Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all, what two variable do you want to compare? It's just a matter of placing an if before the echo, where do you echo the first example line if up or the second echo line if down.

Comment: I want to compare two values of single variable. here value of ftse keep on change and new value is store every-time. I want to compare those value i.e. new value with past most recent value and according to that i want to print in green color or red.

Comment: Isn't that just: if( mostRecentValue > notMostRecentValue) echo "greeStuff" else echo "redStuff" ?